# Bad performance when joining two sets based on a

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, set, query-optimization

To better illustrate my problem picture the following data set that has Rooms that contain a "range" of animals. To represent the range, each animal is assigned a sequence number in a separate table. There are different animal types and the sequence is "reset" for each of them.

**Table A**

| RoomId | StartAnimal | EndAnimal | GroupType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Monkey | Bee | A |
| 1 | Lion | Buffalo | A |
| 2 | Ant | Frog | B |

**Table B**

| Animal | Sequence | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Monkey | 1 | A |
| Zebra | 2 | A |
| Bee | 3 | A |
| Turtle | 4 | A |
| Lion | 5 | A |
| Buffalo | 6 | A |
| Ant | 1 | B |
| Frog | 2 | B |

**Desired Output**

Getting all the animals for each Room based on their Start-End entries, e.g.

| RoomId | Animal |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Monkey |
| 1 | Zebra |
| 1 | Bee |
| 1 | Lion |
| 1 | Buffalo |
| 2 | Ant |
| 2 | Frog |

I have been able to get the desired output by first creating a view where the rooms have their start and end sequence numbers, and then Join them with the animal list comparing the ranges.

The problem is that this is performing poorly in my real data set where there are around 10k rooms and around 340k animals. Is there a different (better) way to go about this that I'm not seeing?

Example fiddle I'm working with: https://dbfiddle.uk/RnagCTf0

The query I tried is

```
WITH fullAnimals AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT(RoomId), a.[Animal], ta.[GroupType], a.[sequence] s1, ae.[sequence] s2
    FROM  [TableA] ta
        LEFT JOIN [TableB] a ON a.[Animal] = ta.[StartAnimal] AND a.[Type] = ta.[GroupType]
        LEFT JOIN [TableB] ae ON ae.[Animal] = ta.[EndAnimal] AND ae.[Type] = a.[Type]
)
SELECT DISTINCT(r.Id), Name, b.[Animal], b.[Type]
FROM [TableB] b
    LEFT JOIN fullAnimals ON (b.[Sequence] >= s1 AND b.[Sequence] <= s2)
    INNER JOIN [Rooms] r ON (r.[Id] = fullAnimals.[RoomId]) --this is a third table that has more data from the rooms
WHERE b.[Type] = fullAnimals.[GroupType]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Post the table definitions and actual query in the question itself. 340K isn't a lot of data. If the columns are covered by indexes you shouldn't have problems.

Comment: Are the JOIN and `sequence` columns indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, to remove the aggregations, is to use the following joins:

- between TableA and TableB, to gather "*a.StartAnimal*" id
- between TableA and TableB, to gather "*a.EndAnimal*" id
- between TableB and the previous two TableBs, to gather only the rows that have b.Sequence between the two values of "*a.StartAnimal*" id and "*b.StartAnimal*" id, on the matching "*Type*".
- between Table A and Rooms, to gather room infos

```
SELECT r.*, b.Animal, b.Type
FROM       TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b1 ON a.StartAnimal = b1.Animal
INNER JOIN TableB b2 ON a.EndAnimal = b2.Animal
INNER JOIN TableB b  ON b.Sequence BETWEEN b1.Sequence AND b2.Sequence
                    AND a.GroupType = b.Type
INNER JOIN Rooms r   ON r.Id = a.roomId
```

Check the updated demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/gBt4sCmh).

Comment: Seems like I was overcomplicating things, this is much cleaner and is performing better on my end.

Comment: oh @lemon , what if there was an additional table that held a historical record of Animals, and we had to return results only where the Animal is in that table as well? The caveat being that an animal can have multiple records in the historical table. If I do an additional INNER JOIN on that animal, then it duplicates results because of the multiple entries in the historical table

Comment: In that case you shall first need to apply a DISTINCT on that table, to retrieve unique values for each row (animal), then apply the "filtering join" on the output you're currently getting. The weight of that aggregation is dependent on the cardinality of this new table has. In the end, lots of joins and Panagiotis's suggestion about indices can only improve the overall speed of the whole join matching operations even further.

Comment: I tried doing that (or something like that) by using the WITH AS ( getting Distinct animals here ) syntax, then using that output as an additional INNER JOIN in the original query from your answer, but it seems to have tanked the performance. is there a way to get the unique IDs in the JOIN itself?

Comment: If you'd like to avoid aggregation, then you need to apply filtering. You could try computing the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Animal) AS rn`, then in the join condition you use two conditions: one that matches animal with animal, the other one that imposes rn = 1 (`ON cte.Animal = b.Animal AND cte.rn = 1`). If that reveals inefficient, then you can't do much about it unluckily, apart from what we already said in this comments section.